# Tensorflow pruned model of MobileNetV2 has the same size

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

I have a model based on MobileNetV2 with added classification head. I followed a tutorial how to prune model, but obviously, when I pruned model, only classification head is pruned which is not what I need. Is it possible to prune base_model and then add it to my model?

**Base model:**

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(
  input_shape=INPUT_IMG_SHAPE,
  include_top=False,
  weights='imagenet',
  pooling='avg'
)
```

**Actual model:**

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(base_model)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(
    units=NUM_CLASSES,
    activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax,
    kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l=0.01)
))
```

I tried to prune base_model like this and then add it to actual `model`, but the size of gzipped model is the same.

**Pruned base model:**

```
import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfmot
prune_low_magnitude = tfmot.sparsity.keras.prune_low_magnitude
prune_base_model=prune_low_magnitude(base_model)
```

Added to `model`:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(prune_base_model)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(
    units=10,
    activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax,
    kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l=0.01)
))
```

Is it even possible to prune it like that?

Comment: The first one is not model pruning, it's replacing the classification head to fit the model to different problems (with different amount of classes for example). As for the second one, it should work, as the `prune_low_magnitude` function returns a wrapped model. Did you try your approach?

Comment: I wanted to show what I tried, so `base` and `actual` are just for context. Adding `prune_base_model` to `model` doesn't work. When I call: 

model_for_export = tfmot.sparsity.keras.strip_pruning(model)

the gzipped size of model and model for export is almost the same.

Comment: You could try to wrap the whole sequential model in the `prune_base_model` call.

Comment: No, somehow doesn't work either. I tried to create reproducible notebook here:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1q3Jhbt2O2n4qtlSICAeC03Y7HwQSfa2f?usp=sharing

Comment: Your notebook produces multiple errors for me. You have to provide the tf model optimization library with `!pip install tensorflow-model-optimization`. Then there are at least 2 other errors for me when I try to run it.

Comment: It runs for me now and you get different file sizes, even if the differences are very small. But that could just mean that there is not a whole lot to prune.

Comment: Why are the differences that small? MobileNetV2 is quite a big model. It seems that only added classification header is pruned. Could it be because model layers are set as non trainable?

Comment: I found that model is pruned, but it doesn't make it significantly smaller. When I changed batch size and number of epochs, it was changed.